# MLE for a Borel distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I would appreciate help with on how to find the estimation $\hat{\beta}_{ML}$ for a Borel distribution. I am doing something wrong in, my guess, the likelihood function and therefore the final answer is also wrong. The question is from an old exam without an solution in the course *statistic inference theory*.

> Suppose that we have an iid sample $X_{1:n} = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$
> from a Borel distribution with probability mass function of $X_i$ given
> by $$P(X_i=x:\beta)=\frac{1}{x!}(\beta x)^{x-1}e^{-\beta x}, x=1,2,..$$ Derive the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\beta}_{ML}$ for $\beta$.

I am trying to do this by (1) computing the likelihood function $L(\beta)$, (2) computing the log-likelihood $l(\beta)$, (3) computing the score function $S(\beta)$ and finally (4) solving the score equation in order to obtain the estimate $\hat{\beta}_{ML}$. However, I'm having a bit of a problem getting the correct likelihood and log-likelihood and as a result all the following steps are incorrect.

**My solution**: I started with (1) and got the following $$L(\beta)=\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^nx_k!}exp\left(-\beta \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)\prod_{k=1}^n(\beta x_k)^{x_k-1}$$ and left it like that since I found no further way to simplify $\prod_{k=1}^n(\beta x_k)^{x_k-1}$. So then I continued on to (2)and got the following $$l(\beta) = -log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)-\beta\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k-1\right)log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\beta x_k\right)$$ which I then tried to find the score function of in order to solve the score equation $S(\beta)=0$ but without success. But when I tried solving it, it looked like the following $$S(\beta)=-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k-1}{\sum_{k=1}^n\beta x_k}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^nx_k=-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k + \frac{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k-1}{\beta n}$$.

However by solving $S(\beta)=0$ it does not give me the correct answer, which should be $\hat{\beta}_{ML}=1-\frac{1}{\bar{x}}$, would someone help me with what I am doing wrong? I am guessing that I should do something more with the product that I left in $L(\beta)$ - so what am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The last term in the log of the likelihood should be something like $\sum _{k=1}^n (x_k-1) (\log (\beta )+\log (x_k))$.  So, yes, it is the take of the log of the product that needs fixing.

Comment: @JeanMarie But this is a discrete distribution on the positive integers.

Comment: Sorry, I was mislead by the use of letter $x$ which is usually $n$ for discrete distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\bar x$ be the sample mean; then the kernel of the likelihood for a single observation is $$\mathcal L(\beta \mid x) \propto \beta^{x-1} e^{-\beta x} = \beta^{-1} (\beta e^{-\beta})^x.$$  Then the kernel for the likelihood of the full sample is
$$\mathcal L(\beta \mid x_{1:n}) \propto \beta^{-n} (\beta e^{-\beta})^{n \bar x}.$$  Consequently the log-likelihood is
$$\ell(\beta \mid x_{1:n}) = -n \log \beta + n\bar x \log (\beta e^{-\beta}) \propto  -\beta \bar x + (\bar x - 1) \log \beta.$$  Computing the derivative with respect to $\beta$ yields
$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta} \propto -\bar x + \frac{\bar x - 1}{\beta},$$ hence the unique critical point is $$\hat \beta = 1 - \frac{1}{\bar x}.$$